# Conditional expectation and its multiplication

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the ross's book, Stochastic Processes, he asserts the following argument.

---

Let ${f_{\tau}}_n(x)=\frac{n}{t} (\frac{x}{t})^{n-1}, \quad 0<x<t$. Then $E[\frac{1}{\tau_n}|\tau_n>y] \cdot P\{\tau_n > y\} = \int_y^t \frac{1}{x} \frac{n}{t} (\frac{x}{t})^{n-1} dx$.

---

To obtain the result above, I think maybe he used the relationship below:

$E[\frac{1}{\tau_n}|\tau_n>y] \cdot P\{\tau_n > y\}$

$= \int \frac{1}{x} \cdot f(x|x>y) \cdot P\{x>y\}dx = \int \frac{1}{x} \cdot f(x,x>y)dx = \int_y^t \frac{1}{x} \cdot f(x)dx$

The above is just my guess. However, if this is true, how $P(\tau_n >y)$ can move into the integral part (the expectation part)? Or if my guess is wrong, how I can get the result Ross asserts?

Thanks!

Comment: More generally, and rather strikingly so, the author uses that $$E(X\mid A)P(A)=E(X\mathbf 1_A)\qquad A=(X>x)$$ and, by definition, if $X$ has density $f_X$, then $$E(X;A)=\int_AXdP=\int_x^\infty zf_X(z)dz.$$ Forcing conditional distributions into this seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because $\mathsf P(\tau>y)$ is a constant.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\tfrac 1 \tau \mid \tau>y) & = \int_0^t \tfrac 1 x \;f_\tau(x\mid \tau >y) \operatorname d x
\\ & = \int_0^t \frac 1 x \;\frac{f_\tau(x)\mathbf 1_{x>y}}{\mathsf P(\tau>y)} \operatorname d x
\\ & = \frac 1{\mathsf P(\tau>y)}\int_y^t \frac{f_\tau(x)}{x}\operatorname d x\end{align}$$

---

**Note:** $f_\tau(x\mid \tau>y)=\dfrac{f_\tau(x)\mathbf 1_{x>y}}{\mathsf P(\tau>y)}$ is *analogous* to the discrete case: $$\begin{align}\Pr(X=x\mid X>y) & = \dfrac{\Pr(X=x, X>y)}{\Pr(X>y)}\\ & = \dfrac{\Pr(X=x)\mathbf 1_{x>y}}{\Pr(X>y)} \end{align}$$

Comment: Then, does $E[\frac{1}{\tau_n}|\tau_n>y]$ mean whatever $\tau_n$ is, it assumes that $\tau_n$ is greater than $y$? Thus, we need to consider the probability that $\tau_n$ is greater than $y$. Is it right? Thanks for your help!!!